# Change direction to rtl Image Intervention Text()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

How can I change the text direction to rtl in Image Intervention Laravel?

All I can see from the docs are font, fontsize, color etc...
Is this possible? What I want to do is write a text on top of an image but my language is rtl.

Comment: https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/630

Comment: @fubar Thanks but the laravel require does not work. Composer says nothing to install

Comment: You couldn’t install the AR-PHP library using Composer?

Comment: Yes. I included in required and composer says ‘nothing to install or update’